# Angulajs : ng-repeat in array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, controller

I'm hoping someone can help.

I'm new to AngularJS and undergoing my first project using the framework. I'm attempting to create a simple checkout system.

I have a html page with 2 columns; the left is a list of items, and the right is the basket(cart) containing the items.

This is the list of items;

```
<div class='panel-body'>
<div ng-repeat='m in merchandiseCtrl.merchandise'>
    <div class='row'>
        <!--START OF NESTED COLUMN-->

        <div class='col-xs-2'>
            <!--START OF LEFT NEST COLUMN-->
            <img ng-src='../images/{{ m.id }}.jpg' class='img-responsive'>
        </div>

        <div class='col-sm-4'>
            <strong>{{m.name}}</strong>
            <br>
            {{m.desc}}
        </div>
        <!--END OF LEFT NEST COLUMN-->

        <div class='col-xs-6'>
            <!--START OF RIGHT NEST COLUMN-->
            <div class='col-xs-6'>
                <!--MORE NESTED COLUMNS ... -->
                {{m.price}}
            </div>

            <div class='col-xs-2'>
                <input type='text' class='form-control input-sm' value='1'>
            </div>

            <div class='col-xs-4'>
                <button ng-click='merchandiseCtrl.addItemToBasket(m)' type='button' class='btn btn-primary' ng-click=''>Add Item</button>
            </div>
            <!--START OF LEFT NEST COLUMN-->
        </div>

    </div>
    <!--END OF NESTED COLUMN-->
    <hr>
</div>
<!--END OF ANGULAR REPEAT-->
```

This is the controller currently in use.

```
//Controller:
app.controller('MerchandiseController', function(merchandiseService) {

    var that = this;

    merchandiseService.getMerchandise().success(function (data){
        that.merchandise = data;
    });

    var basket = [];
    this.addItemToBasket = function(item){

        console.log(item.name);
        basket.push(item);
        console.log(basket.length)
    },

    this.removeItem = function(item){
        console.log("remove me" + item.name);
    },

    this.total = function(){


        return total;
    }


});
```

Now, what I intend to do is populate the basket(cart) with item's I have added to the array 'basket' that is declared in the controller. I'm unsure on how I access the 'basket' array in html to repeat the content.

This is the basket(cart) I have so far (I'd like to print out the items in the basket array) ...

```
<div ng:repeat='m in merchandiseCtrl BASKET???' class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-3'>{{ m.name }}</div>
<div class='col-sm-3'>Quantity</div>
<div class='col-sm-3'>{{ m.price }}</div>
<div class='col-sm-3 '>
    <button ng-click='merchandiseCtrl.removeItem(m)' type='button' class='btn btn-link btn-xs'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>
    </button>
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

The same way you repeat the items in the list. 
You don't use var to store the basket collection, you attach it to the scope:

```
that.basket = [];
that.addItemToBasket = function(item){
    that.basket.push(item);
},
```

And you just repeat it in the html:

```
<div ng:repeat='m in merchandiseCtrl.basket' class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-3'>{{ m.name }}</div>
<div class='col-sm-3'>Quantity</div>
<div class='col-sm-3'>{{ m.price }}</div>
<div class='col-sm-3 '>
<button ng-click='merchandiseCtrl.removeItem(m)' type='button' class='btn btn-link btn-xs'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>
</button>
```

And also, just for the sake of clarity, attach all scope properties and methods to `that`, don't mix `this` and `that`. I would also rename "that" to something like "vm" or "merchandiseVm"